# Is there a computing term for form elements that have “relevant” values?

Tags: programming

Is there a word for form elements that have “relevant” values?  If there is, what is it?

By “relevant” values, I mean values that we want to process or which are needed for processing. These values are not necessarily user inputs because they can be hidden fields or static fields.

Elements like the submit button, form headings, and labels are examples of form elements that have irrelevant values.

I guess I’m looking for a programming term because in programming, those are considered form elements and they have “values” in a programming sense.

Comment: Perhaps "Informative"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about *Naming, including naming programming variables/classes*

Comment: What you call "elements" are called "controls". Not sure why labels or buttons properties should be "irrelevant". I am not seeing a distinction, thus far. You need to explain better.

Comment: @TrevorD this is not naming variables but I'm looking for a rather generic technical term (if one exists) for those kind of form elements.

Comment: @Pam I see "irrelevant" values as data that I (or I think usually most) do not need. For instance, the submit button's value is "Apply now". I don't need that value. I'm more interested in the values that were inputted by the user because those are data that I'll need for processing. But this is not limited to data inputted by the user as I mentioned above. Hope this comment helps.

Comment: You could try "salient", although I think "relevant" works fine as you've used it.

Comment: It’s a shame English doesn’t have a gerundive like Latin—that would have been a perfect match. I suppose you could coin your own word, like saying that these elements are known as _procedenda_ (‘things that are to be/should be processed’), because I don’t know of any established term for them. There’s a good chance you won’t be understood if you call them something like that, of course, so you’d have to start off by explaining what that means … which only pays off if you need to use this term an awful lot.

Comment: @Pax IMHO it's *Naming* - the restriction was not limited to variables.

Comment: @TrevorD, it’s not really a ‘what should I call this thing?’ question, but rather an ‘is there a word for this thing?’ question, which is not usually considered naming. Of course, since the answer seems to be that there _isn’t_ a word, you’re left with making up a new one, which is naming—but that’s in the answers more than in the question itself.

Comment: +1 This is not a naming the variable question. It is a request for a term of art in web programming.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet I would accept your comment (about gerundives) as an answer, just also mention explicitly that there is no such computing term (if there really isn't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've very recently seen the term "data elements" used to describe all the fields contained in an app we're working on, in the context of asking for a list of all of them (Which, considering the size of this app? Is going to be a huge undertaking).

Terminology is tricky, because different jargon will mean different things in different fields, even within the same discipline.  I suggest that if you're trying to refer to a specific item's elements, you simply refer to it as [That Item]'s elements.  No need for a special term to describe them.

Though there is a particular computer term for the data that goes INTO a program, regardless of whether the user inputs them or not.  "Parameters" are set at the start of a program, method, or other coded action, and though they don't include things like the "submit buttons" and other elements of whatever you might be working on, it could help you identify what part of the program you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Without a little more context it's hard to tell for certain what you need, but normally I'd see the term "set" or "class" used.

Example:

> This set of variables define the person's attributes.

Answer (score -1):

"Required fields" is what I usually use and see.

Comment: That means something else entirely: fields in a form that must be filled out for the form to be submitted. Some of the elements that the asker is looking for may well not be required (or indeed fields) on the actual page/form.